# Actual Pipelining, not Batch Processing, in PHP+Redis

Tags: php, redis

There's a lot of information on "pipelining" in PHP+Redis on the web. However, When you actually start looking at the examples, not a single one of them does actual pipelining. All they do is batch processing. As examples, let's take Predis ->pipeline() (https://github.com/nrk/predis) and Phpredis ->multi() (https://github.com/nicolasff/phpredis). They basically suspend execution of commands and instead collect the commands into a buffer, then execute them as a batch when calling ->execute() / ->exec() later.

Disadvantages:
- has to allocate a command buffer that can grow large for many commands
- needs a round-trip to the server once for every batch of commands

The behaviour I would expect from pipelining mode is: Start sending commands as soon as I pass them to the client, not buffer them. Return before the response for a command has arrived. Allow to send more and more commands while the previous ones are "in flight". Once in a while, collect responses from the client that have arrived, without waiting for responses that have not yet arrived.

The strange thing is that the examples actually pass constants to the client that are called "pipelining", yet they describe the behaviour as batch processing.

Big question: How can you actually put those clients into pipelining mode?

Comment: you'd have to keep a queue of pending db commands, and match up responses with queries.  The db calls in php would return immediately, with status delivered later; php might have to roll back on error.  It's event-based programming; rather un-PHP-like, but is exactly how the nodejs beanstalkd interface I wrote works.

Comment: The queue of pending DB commands would be in the Redis server and/or the network socket. Queueing commands on the client-side would defeat pipelining again. With regard to errors, I'd expect the same effect as if I waited for the response to the erroneous command first, then sent further commands, just without the time for the round-trip.

Comment: Not pending to be sent, but pending a response:  the php call would return immediately.  However, internally it would have to track what's still outstanding to be able to report errors.

Comment: Just a sidenote: python's redis-py implementation has similar limitations, see [here](https://github.com/andymccurdy/redis-py/issues/451). I benchmarked custom batching of redis commands in msgpack containers, executed by a server-side Lua script, which outperforms redis pipelining (see post). Therefore, it has become a non-issue for me.